# Use VBA code to click on a button on webpage

Tags: vba, click, html

I am editing a vba program and want to code the vba to click on a button in a webpage. The html for the button is:

```
<input type="image" src="/lihtml/test_button3.gif" align="left" alt="File_Certificate_Go"/>
```

I imagine I would have to set a variable to getElementBy??? and then variable.click, but I can't figure out how exactly to get the element (because it doesn't have a name or id, and I can't give it one because it is not my webpage).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something on the lines of:

```
Set tags = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagname("Input")

For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.alt = "File_Certificate_Go" Then
        tagx.Click
    End If
Next
```

Where wb is the WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you couldn't give the element an id?

i.e.:

```
<input id='myButton' type=image src="/lihtml/test_button3.gif" align=left alt=File_Certificate_Go>
```

then:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').click()
```

*edit*: Based on your comment, you'd have to grab all input elements on the page, and then cycle through them looking for the one that makes your input unique:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
for (var i=0; i< elms.length; i++) 
    if(elms[i].src = '/lihtml/test_button3.gif') { elms[i].click(); }
```

Something along those lines anyway

Comment: I cannot change the html because it is not my webpage.