# How to use Excel VBA to click a web CSS button?

Tags: css, excel, vba

I am creating a macro with Excel VBA that will submit an entry into an online database using information from an Excel spreadsheet. During this entry process, the macro needs to click on a CSS button. It isn't a form button, does not have an input type, no name, no id, and no source image except for a background image. I think my only hopes are either to click on the button based on the div class. Can anyone help?
The button is here :

```
<div class="v-captiontext">
    By Ankit
</div>
<td class="v-tabsheet-tabitemcell v-tabsheet-tabitemcell-selected" style="">
    <div class="v-         tabsheet-tabitem v-tabsheet-tabitem-selected">
        <div class="v-caption" style="width: 39px;">
            <div class="v-captiontext">
                By LOT</div>
            <div class="v-caption-clearelem">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I can't see any button in your HTML. Do you mean you are trying to click on one of the DIVs?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Remou's answer on this thread: [Use VBA code to click on a button on webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373268/use-vba-code-to-click-on-a-button-on-webpage)

Here is a first stab in your issue, you could try this:

```
Set tags = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagname("div")

For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.class = "v-caption-clearelem" Then
        tagx.Click
    End If
Next
```

Yet, I've never tried to use the `Click` method on a div.