# Click on link using VBA

Tags: vba

I am hoping to get some help here. I am trying to automate downloading a file off a site which requires me to click on the link for every search.

**Here is the link html info:**

```
(a class="icon-xls-export" href="/us/products/239505/ishares-us-consumer-goods-etf/1395165510754.ajax?fileType=csv&amp;fileName=IYK_holdings&amp;dataType=fund" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239505/ishares-us-consumer-goods-etf/1395165510754.ajax?fileT_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">
Detailed Holdings and Analytics </a)
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub Navigate_Web()

For Each Cell In Range("A1:A1") 'location of ticker symbol

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239505/" & Cell.Value & "?referrer=tickerSearch"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set objInputs = IE.document.getElementsByclassname("icon-xls-export")

Next Cell
End Sub
```

I can open the site no problem, but I keep receiving an error message for Object does not support this property or method.

So any help here would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please format your question correctly, code blocks etc etc :)

Anyway...Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
Set tags = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagname("Input")

For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.alt = "File_Certificate_Go" Then
        tagx.Click
    End If
Next
```

Where wb is the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Not your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373268/use-vba-code-to-click-on-a-button-on-webpage

Comment: Stop following me :P It's just helpful info and linking out of the question just causes hassle. I've made the effort to get the info because i want to help, i don't give a crap about any fake internet points :)

Comment: Applogies if my initial question wasn't clear. I received a code error on the get element by class line where error message is "object does not support this property or method."

Comment: I can't use the tags.alt because alt doesn't exist. For every pages unique identifier appears to be the class name. So how do I use onclick based on the class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this.

```
Public Sub OpenWebXLS()
' *************************************************
' Define Workbook and Worksheet Variables
' *************************************************
Dim wkbMyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wkbWebWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksWebWorkSheet As Worksheet

Set wkbMyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

' *************************************************
' Open The Web Workbook
' *************************************************
Workbooks.Open ("https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239505/ishares-us-consumer-goods-etf/1395165510754.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=IYK_holdings&dataType=fund")

' *************************************************
' Set the Web Workbook and Worksheet Variables
' *************************************************
Set wkbWebWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksWebWorkSheet = ActiveSheet

' *************************************************
' Copy The Web Worksheet To My Workbook and Rename
' *************************************************
wksWebWorkSheet.Copy After:=wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = "MyNewWebSheet"

' *************************************************
' Close the Web Workbook
' *************************************************
wkbMyWorkbook.Activate
wkbWebWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Selector:**

You could use a CSS selector of

```
a[onclick*=https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239505/ishares-us-consumer-goods-etf/1395165510754.ajax]
```

Element with `a` tag having attribute `onclick` with value containing `https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239505/ishares-us-consumer-goods-etf/1395165510754.ajax`

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

Apply with `.querySelector` method of `document`

```
ie.document.querySelector("a[onclick*=https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239505/ishares-us-consumer-goods-etf/1395165510754.ajax]").Click
```