# Clicking a button in Internet Explorer using VBA (getElementsByClassName)

Tags: html, excel, vba, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to click a button within an Internet Explorer window using VBA and HTML. The button has no "id" so I have to locate it by "classname."

The button's HTML code is as follows:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only`"
```

VBA Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Const cURL = "xxxxxx.com"
Const cUsername = "xxxxxx"
Const cPassword = "xxxxxx"

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim UserNameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim SignInButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
Dim CVBATButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate cURL

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set doc = IE.document



'A previous login window that leads me into a new window, where I need to click a button.

Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)
Set UserNameInputBox = doc.getElementById("BIA_Login")
UserNameInputBox.Value = cUsername
Set PasswordInputBox = doc.getElementById("BIA_Pass")
PasswordInputBox.Value = cPassword
Set SignInButton = doc.getElementById("login")
SignInButton.Click

'It's this portion of the code below that I'm struggling with

Set doc = IE.document
Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
Set CVBATButton = doc.getElementsByClassName("ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only")
CVBATButton.Click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same Error,
try this (it worked for me):

```
Set CVBATButton = doc.getElementsByClassName("ui-button ui-widget ui-state-
default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only")
  For Each btn In CVBATButton
     btn.Click
     Exit For
  Next
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a collection. You will need to access the first index, or iterate over the collection.

```
Set CVBATButton = doc.getElementsByClassName("ui-button ui-widget ...")(1)
CVBATButton.Click
```

Comment: So I understand that getElementById differs from getElementsByClassName in that the latter returns an array and that I need to access the first index of that classname, but how do I actually click the button after I have selected the correct index

Comment: is the (1) a VBA thing?

Comment: @elfwyn Yes, that is how you get the first element in an array.

Comment: ok... deleted my answer since I can't be sure it is compatible with VBA.

Comment: @Davey `.Click` is fine.

Comment: @4castle Well after making that fix I'm getting a Runtime error 91 of Object variable not set with "CVBATButton.click" highlighted

Comment: Really? It seems to work [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2373837/5743988). Maybe the array is empty?

Comment: Do you know of a way to return `Set CVBATButton = doc.getElementsByClassName("ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-text-only")(1)`

Comment: You could use `querySelector` if you want to select the first element with those classes, or use `querySelectorAll` to get an array of all the elements with those classes.

Comment: Nothing seems to work. Anytime I try anything I get that same Runtime error unfortunately. :/