# How to use VBA to run the onclick event?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to navigate through a website using VBA, but I can't figure out how to execute the onclick event shown below? Any suggestions? This is one cell part of a table of about 10 other options.

```
</tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.cursor=&#39;pointer&#39;" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;wizAttendance$grvCampus&#39;,&#39;Select$1&#39;)">
                <td>Anaheim</td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use VBA code to click on a button on webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373268/use-vba-code-to-click-on-a-button-on-webpage)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Excel VBA to click on a button in Internet Explorer, when the button has no “name” associated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28153744/11683)